# Display plot on GUI using matplotlib and PyGObject

Tags: matplotlib, gtk3, pygobject

I have built an application using Glade and PyGObject. Now, I am trying to include a section on my GUI which can display plots based on some selection. After some research, I found that I can include plots generated using matplotlib as seen in this example: https://github.com/tobias47n9e/GTK3-Matplotlib-Cookbook/blob/master/examples/matplotlibwindow.py

I tried the example and it works fine. Following the code, I added a scrolled window (**to the grid in the main window**) using the following line:

```
self.scrolledwin = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwin")
```

generated a plot and set it to the scrolled window using the same lines in the code:

```
def set_charts(self):

    fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

    N = 20
    theta = linspace(0.0, 2 * pi, N, endpoint=False)
    radii = 10 * random.rand(N)
    width = pi / 4 * random.rand(N)

    bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

    for r, bar in zip(radii, bars):
        bar.set_facecolor(cm.jet(r / 10.))
        bar.set_alpha(0.5)

    ax.plot()

    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.set_size_request(400,400)
    self.scrolledwin.add_with_viewport(canvas)
```

However, in my application, the scrolled window section is blank and does not show the plot.

How can I fix this? Also, will saving the plot with "matplotlib.pyplot.savefig" and then displaying the image hamper the performance?

Comment: Have yo tried `self.canvas.show()` or `self.scrolledwin.show()` or even `self.your_main_window.show_all()`? That's what seems to be missing.

Comment: self.my_main_window.show_all() was there. Adding canvas.show()/self.scrolledwin.show_all() worked. If you can add that as the answer I will accept it. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be missing in your `set_charts` method is a `self.canvas.show()` and `self.scrolledwin.show()`. Every time you add something to the gui you have to call its `show` method or the `show_all` method of its container widget.

In the example you linked, all the widgets are added in the same level (the script level) and `my_first_window.show_all()` is called to show the window and all its children at the end.

Since you're adding the `self.scroledwin` and `self.canvas` widgets in a method (I'm assuming, after you've called `self.your_main_window.show_all()`, probably in the `__init__` method) you need to `show` those added widgets in order for them to be displayed.

Source: [Gtk.Widget - gtk-widget-show](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-show)